# Using Spring retry and circuitbreaker in spring boot 1.3.0 release version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

I need to use spring retry and spring circuit breaker in spring boot application with version 1.3.0 Release.
The spring retry version bundles with this version of spring boot i.e. 1.3.0 Release don't support circuit breaker. 
Is it okay if I use Spring retry latest version with spring boot 1.3.0 release. Will it cause any runtime issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.3 is very, very old; it is no longer supported; the oldest supported version of Boot is 2.1.14.

Comment: Yes Gary but the application is in production and upgrading boot version is not possible as of now. There should not be an issue if I use managed version of spring retry i.e. 1.1.2 RELEASE right ? With this version of spring retry, I can use retry functionality but not the circuit breaker which is present in 1.2.5 retry version. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The latest Boot 1.3.x version is 1.3.8 (nearly 4 years old). It pulls in retry 1.1.3. I don't believe you will have any problems overriding the retry version to 1.2.5, or even 1.3.0. But you really need to consider getting on supported versions of all these projects.